# Secure sending/retrieving of data

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, cryptography

I would like to be able to send and retrieve data in a semi-secure way without having to use HTTPS or SSL.

Currently, I am POSTing data to the server using a salted MD5 hash digest like so (to prevent argument tampering):

http://www.myserver.com?name=John&digest=ed076287532e86365e841e92bfc50d8c

But I would also like encrypt the plain-text data on the client, then decrypt it on the server back into plain text so that the data looks something like:

http://www.myserver.com?name=sK5E4Ld4sw5ie&digest=ed076287532e86365e841e92bfc50d8c

What's a good method to use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to include pre-shared key (AES, for instance) in client and the same on server.
Or, use RSA keypair (public on client, private one on server), however RSA encrypted parameter will take more space.

Comment: Is one method preferred over the other (AES vs RSA)?

Comment: Using AES, if someone will reverse your client code, he will be able to decrypt all sent packets, however, getting only the public key part will not have such problem.

Comment: Jesse, It depends on your needs. AES is a symmetric cryptographic algorithm, while RSA is an asymmetric (or public key) cryptographic algorithm.

Comment: You can also use both to get the best of both worlds. Use RSA encryption to transmit a shared random AES key, then use the AES key for all future communications. RSA is secure even though the public key is transmitted unencrypted, allowing secure transmission of a previously-unknown AES key between client and server. Then, you can take advantage of the higher performance of AES, which has simpler math and a smaller key and chunk size than your average RSA algorithm.

Comment: If both the client and the server know the AES key, why would I need to generate and transfer it between them using RSA? (I'm new to encryption, so bear with me).

Comment: You would use RSA to transmit a random AES key generated at runtime and not known to both parties. This makes your code decompile-proof; instead of a hard-coded key that can be discovered by examining the MSIL, you can generate a random one that isn't known at compile-time. Then, an attacker would only be able to know how you generate one, which is far more difficult to use against you.

Comment: Remember that for this, you need the parties to be able to verify the other party's public key (and signatures), otherwise, the keys could be exchanged with an attacker. Overall, this mimics the TLS handshake, but isn't quite that. It quite easy to make mistakes when designing your own replica.

Comment: You may also want to look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange

Comment: Now I have an issue. RSA uses a public key and a private key. If I send data to the server that has been encrypted with the public RSA key, how is the server supposed to decrypt that data if it doesn't know the private RSA key?

Comment: Why it doesn't know? You pre-populated your client with public key, which corresponds to server's key.

Comment: Of course, I had it backwards! I was having the client generate the RSA keys instead of the server...But then, wouldn't it make more sense to also have the server generate the AES key, and hand it to the client with RSA encryption? (as opposed to having the client generate the AES key and handing it to the server)

Comment: In your scenario, since server has private key, client should generate AES key (instead of server), and sent it encrypted to the server, so server will be able to decrypt it

Answer (score 0):

Sending the digest (MD5 or other) will not prevent tampering unless it can be verified (typically, against a signature and a certificate the server knows). An attacker could otherwise easily modify the request's entity and the digest in the URI at the same time. You'd certainly need to sign the digest with your private key, assuming that the knows your public key in advance to verify it against.

Although you say you don't want to use SSL/TLS, you should really look into it, since home-made crypto is rarely as secure as you'd like (see your own example). This should provide you with integrity (no tampering) and confidentiality (encryption), provided you use keys and/or certificates appropriately.

If you want to encrypt the entity, you could consider:

- PGP/OpenPGP/GPG (you could use it in C# with BouncyCastle)
- [XML encryption](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/) (and probably XML DSig).
- [HTTPsec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPsec) (although I'm not sure how "proven" it is, and I don't know of any C# implementation)

Comment: The input for the MD5 is heavily salted, so they won't be able to simply compute a new MD5 for the tampered parameters unless they decompile the client.

Comment: @Jesse, sure, but you're using the same salt for all requests, then. I wouldn't rely on that for proper security.

Comment: @Jesse A salt is a random value that's transmitted with the hash to prevent rainbow table attacks. What you want is an HMAC, keyed with a secret key shared by client and server. You also need a nonce, to prevent replay attacks.